# How do I allow /Controller/Id in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to visit this url

```
/thread/123
```

Where `123` is the thread `id`.

I can't figure out how to set up my routes or whatever it is.

I thought to add `thread` to my **HomeController**, but it appears that it only works if I go to `/home/thread`.

How do I set up this project so the url `/thread/123` will work?

I tried `/thread` as a controller but it seemed like it thought `123` was an Action Method and the other attempt had thread be in Home rather then root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to add a Route designated for this URI

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Thread", // Route name
        "thread/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Thread", action = "Display", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

**very important:** Add your new route ABOVE the "Default" Route!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize order matters. (I used other software which looks at it as most/least specific)

Comment: yes, b/c the asp.net mvc framework picks 1st route that could match.

Comment: Do I want id = optional? Because the id is required and /thread doesnt make sense. Does the action display mean anything?

Comment: thats a good question: I usually allow optional so that instead of raising an error, if no parameter is given I either use latest thread or give user a list of threads to choose from. This creates more robust functionality. But this is a form/functionality/choice issue.

Comment: ah ha. Ok. So I added the router above default. /thread gets a 404. Did i do something wrong? I seen errors when it complains about not finding views but this is a straight up 404. -edit- nevermind. I needed to add the display action to my thread controller

Comment: ok, edit your post to show the route and your controller and action method(names are important)

Comment: I fixed it. Still kind of new but it was obvious after thinking more. +1 will accept when i can